# Hadoop - MapReduce - Mapper output types

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Newbie, learning the hadoop concepts. Based on my understanding the mapper can emit any number of keys and values but they have to be same type. Based on my understanding option 1 looks good, but some website are mentioning it wrong. Can someone confirm this.

For each input key-value pair, mappers can emit:

As many intermediate key value pairs as desired, as long as all the keys have the same type and all the values have the same type

As many intermediate key-value pairs as desired. There are no restrictions on the types of those key-value pairs (i.e., they can be heterogeneous)

As many intermediate key-value pairs as desired, but they cannot be of the same type as the input key-value pair

One intermediate key value pair, but of the same type

Comment: option 1 is correct. Can you provide links to other websites conflicting with point 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Option 1 looks correct.

> As many intermediate key value pairs as desired, as long as all the
>   keys have the same type and all the values have the same type